# Can spawn-fcgi be user for tcp/udp server

Tags: tcp, lighttpd

[Spawn-fcgi](https://github.com/lighttpd/spawn-fcgi) by [lighty labs](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/)

It only uses unix socket functions `socket()`, `bind()`, `connect()`, `listen()`. Is it possible to use it not for FastCGI server, but TCP or UDP server?

Comment: I would contact the developers and ask.  Their website looks small compared to some of the other GitHub projects I've watched.  You might be able to help develop.

Comment: Their website doesn't have a forum. My question is not an issue, so I dunno where to ask.

Comment: Yes but they do have developers.  Read the authors file and find: jan kneschke - jan@kneschke.de and stefan bühler - lighttpd@stbuehler.de